# Can someone say me why this is wrong in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

```
"INSERT INTO estudy(time) VALUES (60)  WHERE id =1"
```

I wanna set that values but I can´t.

Comment: Do you want to INSERT, that is to add new data, or UPDATE, that is to change existing data? There’s no conditions for the first one but there can be for the latter.

Comment: Hey man, thanks!! You opened my eyes, I wanna do UPDATE, therefore I was not getting do it, THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

You seems to want to update a record not insert so use below statement to update a record where `id = 1`.

```
"update estudy set time = 60 WHERE id =1"
```